# Getting invalid column error from SQL Server while using a view

Tags: sql-server, select, left-join

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'naicscode'

The task at hand is querying a table named Xyzfirms201701 and getting the following result in return.

```
 area    sizeclassep    Number of worksites    employment in size class 
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 000000      01               46673                       48975
 000000      02               32105                       54111
```

I am using the following code in order to attempt to produce this:

```
;WITH sizeclasseptable AS 
(
    SELECT 
        area, naicscode, ownership, sizeclassep 
    FROM 
        (SELECT '01' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '02' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '03' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '04' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '05' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '06' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '07' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '08' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership
         UNION SELECT '09' AS sizeclassep, '50' AS ownership) t0
    CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT area FROM xyzfirms201701) t1
)
SELECT
    '000000' AS area,
    t2.[SizeClassep],
    COUNT(*) AS [Number of Worksites],
    SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
FROM
    sizeclasseptable
LEFT JOIN 
    xyzfirms201701 t2 ON t2.area = sizeclasseptable.area 
                      AND t2.naicscode = sizeclasseptable.naicscode
                      AND t2.ownership = sizeclasseptable.ownership
WHERE 
    t2.naicscode LIKE '11%' OR t2.naicscode LIKE '21%'
GROUP BY
    [t2.SizeClassep]
ORDER BY
    [t2.SizeClassep];
```

The purpose of the first section is to have SQL produce an output even if the data does not exist. For example, size classep=09 is going to be nonexistent at times. This represents a company that employs 1,000 or more in a given industry (naicscode). Any ideas as to why I am getting the invalid column error?

Comment: @spencer7593, edits made. Pardon the oversight. I need to slow down on this.

Comment: In your CTE, where do you get the column `naicscode` from?  I don't see it in inner query.

Comment: @spencer7593, by inner query, I assume that you are referring to the second half of it. This begins with "Select '000000' and so on. Am I correct?

Comment: @Eric, by inner query, I assume that you are referring to the second half of it. This begins with "Select '000000' and so on. Am I correct?

Comment: @Calflamesfann I'm referring to the one inside the CTE.  I'll put it in the answer so you can see.

Comment: @Eric, Ok I think that I am coming around. I spell out the 3 other fields but not naicscode. So any ideas how I would include it in the CTE?. There are 350 naics codes. I am attempting to query based on the first two numbers in it.

Comment: @Calflamesfann Where's the `naicscode` information from?

Comment: naicscode is one of 29 columns contained in the xyzfirms201701. Now that I put naicscode in the place mentioned below, getting a similar error about invalid column name t2.sizeclassep

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get the field `naiscode` from?

```
 ;with sizeclasseptable as (
    select area,ownership,sizeclassep 
    from (
        select '01' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '02' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '03' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '04' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '05' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '06' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '07' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '08' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
        union select '09' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
    ) t0
    cross join ( 
        select distinct area from xyzfirms201701 
    ) t1
)
SELECT
    '000000' AS area,
    t2.[SizeClassep],
    COUNT(*) AS [Number of Worksites],
    SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
FROM sizeclasseptable
LEFT JOIN xyzfirms201701 t2 ON t2.area=sizeclasseptable.area 
    --AND t2.naicscode=sizeclasseptable.naicscode
    AND t2.ownership=sizeclasseptable.ownership
WHERE t2.naicscode LIKE '11%' OR t2.naicscode LIKE '21%'
GROUP BY [t2.SizeClassep]
ORDER BY [t2.SizeClassep];
```

How about removing `naicscode` from the CTE since it definitely is in table `xyzfirms201701`.

Comment: I removed naicscode from both the first line of the CTE and the last (select distinct...) and the invalid column naicscode comes up again

Comment: By removing naicscode from the CTE and the left join statement along with taking the brackets of the t2.sizeclassep, that resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `naicscode` in cross join sub query as its missing in CTE, that's the reason you are getting the `Invalid column name` error. Just update the below line as I believe `naicscode` is part of `xyzfirms201701` table.

```
cross join ( select distinct area, naicscode from xyzfirms201701 ) t1
```

**Update**
Final query using alias to CTE table.

```
;with sizeclasseptable as 
(
select t1.area,
       t1.naicscode,
       t0.ownership,
       t0.sizeclassep 
from (
select '01' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '02' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '03' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '04' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '05' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '06' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '07' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '08' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '09' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership) t0
cross join ( select distinct area, naicscode from xyzfirms201701 ) t1
)
SELECT
  '000000' AS area,
  sc.[SizeClassep],
  COUNT(*) AS [Number of Worksites],
  SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
from sizeclasseptable sc
left join xyzfirms201701 t2 
  on t2.area=sc.area 
    and t2.naicscode=sc.naicscode
    and t2.ownership=sc.ownership
WHERE t2.naicscode like '11%' or t2.naicscode like '21%'
GROUP BY [sc.SizeClassep]
ORDER BY [sc.SizeClassep];
```

Comment: Now that I put naicscode in the place mentioned below, getting a similar error about invalid column name t2.sizeclassep. Any ideas?

Comment: sizeclassep is part of sizeclasseptable CTE right? So you should use sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep  instead of t2.sizeclassep in group by and order by clause at the end. (t2 alias is referring to xyzfirms201701  table.)

Comment: check my updates, final query using alias to sizeclasseptable.

Comment: Now, the error is ambiguous column name 'sizeclassep'?

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'sc.SizeClassep'.

Comment: updated aliases to each column, try now. Do you have sizeclassep column in xyzfirms201701  table?

Comment: Yes, there is a column titled sizeclassep

Answer (score 0):

The code below yields the correct answer and no errors. The primary issue is that naicscode is not defined in the CTE and therefore needs to be left out. Because it is not in the CTE, therefore it needs to be removed from the join. If I stopped there, I would get no errors but the values given were incorrect. They were 9 times what they should be. 305 worksites was the correct number but it was given 2745 and so on. From there, adding "and t2.sizeclassep = sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep" to the join statement keeps it from giving 305 results per sizeclassep.

```
;with sizeclasseptable as 
(
select area,ownership,sizeclassep from (
select '01' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '02' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '03' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '04' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '05' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '06' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '07' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '08' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership
union select '09' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership) t0
cross join ( select distinct area from xyzfirms201701 ) t1
)

 SELECT
'000000' AS area,
t2.[SizeClassep],
COUNT(*) AS [Number of Worksites],
SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
from sizeclasseptable
left join xyzfirms201701 t2 
on t2.area=sizeclasseptable.area 
and t2.ownership=sizeclasseptable.ownership
and t2.sizeclassep = sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep
WHERE t2.naicscode like '11%' or t2.naicscode like '21%'
GROUP BY
t2.SizeClassep
ORDER BY
t2.SizeClassep
```